# How to find unity documentation in visual studio using control keys?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to find unity documentation in visual studio using control keys? I used CTRL + ', there is no result. Who can help?

Answer (score 1):

First, position the mouse to the class or class property in which you want to find the documentation on.

Now, press **CTRL+ALT+M** and you will see something like below in Visual Studio:

[image]

Finally press, **CTRL+H** and the documentation should open.

**Note**:
If that is not opening, you have to find the current version of Unity you are using  and download its documentation. If you are using Beta version of Unity you have to [download](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta) documentation by clicking on WINDOWS COMPONENT INSTALLERS and then Documentation.

Comment: thanks, i did it! I just needed to download tools for unity into VS!